# LLvm Jit : How to dereference a runtime pointer from jited code?

Tags: c++, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have a pointer to a floating point number variable in my c++ code. I would like to emit a llvm IR instruction that dereference this pointer in order to access this variable from jited code. How can I emit such an instruction ?

I have tried to convert the pointer to a 64 bit integer constant and then to a float pointer. But when I get malformed IR Code.

```
auto *pointer_as_integer = ConstantInt::get(
    context, APInt(64, reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&variable)));

auto *pointer = builder.CreateIntToPtr(
    pointer_as_integer, Type::getFloatTy(context));

return builder.CreateLoad(
    Type::getFloatTy(context), pointer);
```

I get this when I try to apply the verify pass :

```
Instruction does not dominate all uses!
%PTR = load float, float* inttoptr (i64 140724356577004 to float*)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

When I apply the verification pass. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was elsewhere : I did not set the builder insert point to my function block, resulting in malformed IR code.